# Faster way of redirecting all requests to sanic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sanic

I'm attempting to redirect all requests in `sanic` web server. So, for example, if someone went to `localhost:5595/example/hi` it would forward to a website. I know how to normally do that in `sanic`, but it would be to slow to redirect 100 urls. Is there any faster way of doing this?

Comment: what you mean by that? do you have example?

Comment: Why do you think it would be slow?  Have you actually tried it?  Or do you just mean it is too much typing?  You can do your own route management to avoid having 100 @app.get functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if this is the answer you are looking for. But, if you are asking about making a super crude proxy server in Sanic to redirect all requests, something like this would do (see `server1.py`).

```py
# server1.py
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import redirect

app = Sanic("server1")


@app.route("/<path:path>")
async def proxy(request, path):
    return redirect(f"http://localhost:9992/{path}")


app.run(port=9991)
```

And so we have a place for traffic to go:

```py
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import text

app = Sanic("server1")


@app.route("/<foo>/<bar>")
async def endpoint(request, foo, bar):
    return text(f"Did you know {foo=} and {bar=}?")


app.run(port=9992)
```

Now, let's test it out:

```sh
$ curl localhost:9991/hello/world -Li
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://localhost:9992/hello/world
content-length: 0
connection: keep-alive
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-length: 35
connection: keep-alive
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

Did you know foo='hello' and bar='world'?
```